# I want to remove a line from one character until other character matches

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file with content as follows :

```
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item1': { 'buy': 'bananna', 'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science' },
     'item2': { 'buy': 'apple', 'drink': x'cola',
                'work': 'slow', 
                'eat': 'sweet',
                'travel': 'world' },
     'item3': { 'buy': 'bananna', 
                'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science'}})
Some other content in this file.
```

Now, I want to search for item2 and remove the following content:

```
'item2': { 'buy': 'apple', 'drink': x'cola',
                'work': 'slow', 
                'eat': 'sweet',
                'travel': 'world' },
```

Currently I am doing as `awk '!/'item2'/' filename`. But, this will only delete that particular line and not until closed bracket with comma. I also tried using `pcregrep -Mo 'item2' filename`. But, I am unable to set until `{` and upto `},`.

Also, to note that there is one special case where if I have to remove `item3`, then at the end there will not be comma `,`.

Please suggest on what needs to done?

Comment: Is this supposed to be json?

Comment: no. its look somewhat similar to json. But this is how the file is structured.

Comment: @Kasino  Are you trying to get something as the follwing `sed -n "/'item2': {/,/}/d;p" filename`.  If you are trying to do json file alternation you are better off using `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ perl -0777 -pe '$s="item1"; s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s ; s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s' ip.txt 
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item2': { 'buy': 'apple', 'drink': x'cola',
                'work': 'slow', 
                'eat': 'sweet',
                'travel': 'world' },
     'item3': { 'buy': 'bananna', 
                'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science'}})
Some other content in this file.

$ perl -0777 -pe '$s="item3"; s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s ; s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s' ip.txt 
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item1': { 'buy': 'bananna', 'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science' },
     'item2': { 'buy': 'apple', 'drink': x'cola',
                'work': 'slow', 
                'eat': 'sweet',
                'travel': 'world' }})
Some other content in this file.

$ perl -0777 -pe '$s="item2"; s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s ; s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s' ip.txt 
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item1': { 'buy': 'bananna', 'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science' },
     'item3': { 'buy': 'bananna', 
                'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science'}})
Some other content in this file.
```

- Uses `-0777` to slurp whole file and `s` flag to allow `.*` to match across lines
- `s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s` for elements like `item1` and `item2` where `,` follows `}`
- `s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s` for elements like `item3` where I suspect you need to remove a `,` on the previous line
- `\x27` hex code for single quotes
- just change `$s="item2";` to required element to be removed

**Edit:**

To pass variables from shell (see [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001835/how-do-i-pass-shell-variable-into-a-perl-search-and-replace) for details)

```
$ export var1='item3'
$ perl -0777 -pe '$s=$ENV{var1}; s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s ; s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s' ip.txt 
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item1': { 'buy': 'bananna', 'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science' },
     'item2': { 'buy': 'apple', 'drink': x'cola',
                'work': 'slow', 
                'eat': 'sweet',
                'travel': 'world' }})
Some other content in this file.
```

You can also delete multiple items

```
$ export var1='(item3|item2)'
$ perl -0777 -pe '$s=$ENV{var1}; s/ *\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\},\n*//s ; s/,\s*\x27$s\x27:\s*\{.*?\}(?!,)//s' ip.txt 
some other content in this file
    demo({
     'item1': { 'buy': 'bananna', 'drink': x'cooldrink',
                'work': 'hard', 
                'study': 'science' }})
Some other content in this file.
```

Comment: Small confusion, What if I have item1 value in a variable called `VAR1`
`perl -0777 -pe '$s=$VAR1; ...` This doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Kasino , see edit